# App still trying to receive after device is disconnected

Tags: google-chrome-app, hid

```
chrome.hid.receive(connectionId, myReceiver);
chrome.hid.onDeviceRemoved.addListener(function () {
        isDeviceConnected = false;
        chrome.hid.disconnect(connectionId, function () { }); 
        return;
    });
```

> extensions::lastError:134 Unchecked runtime.lastError while running
>   hid.receive: Transfer failed.

How do I stop Chrome App to stop receiving if device is disconnected?

Comment: What about simply checking the error in the receive callback: `if (chrome.runtime.lastError) return;`?

Comment: @wOxxOm Its kind of working but is it a good practice?